# Folder Clean-Up - Move Subfolders

Tags: vbscript

I've managed to put something together which moves files of a particular extension to a new location and organise into year/month folders based on date modified. Is anybody able to help me modify it to also move subfolders in the source folder into these organised directories? (not just the files in the subfolders, but the folders themselves with the contents). This would be based on the date modified of the subfolder.

```
'Declare Variables
Dim srcDir,dstDir,myDir,objFSO,objFolder,objFiles,objFile,strmonth
Const OverwriteExisting = True

'Create a file sytem object as a base for manipulating files and directories
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Define Directories
srcDir = "C:\"
dstDir = "C:\Presentations"

'Get list of files in source directory
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(srcDir)
Set objFiles = objFolder.Files

'Loop through files and move to relevant folder
For Each objFile In objFiles
    'If file is .csv or .txt 
    If LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name)) = "csv" Or LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name)) = "txt" Or LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name)) = "pptx" Then
        strmonth = Month(objFile.DateLastModified)
        If strmonth = "1" Then
            myDir = dstDir & "\" & Year(objFile.DateLastModified) & " - " & "January"
        ElseIf strmonth = "2" Then
            myDir = dstDir & "\" & Year(objFile.DateLastModified) & " - " & "February"
        ElseIf strmonth = "3" Then
            myDir = dstDir & "\" & Year(objFile.DateLastModified) & " - " & "March"
        ElseIf strmonth = "4" Then
            myDir = dstDir & "\" & Year(objFile.DateLastModified) & " - " & "April"
        ElseIf strmonth = "5" Then
            myDir = dstDir & "\" & Year(objFile.DateLastModified) & " - " & "May"
        ElseIf strmonth = "6" Then
            myDir = dstDir & "\" & Year(objFile.DateLastModified) & " - " & "June"
        ElseIf strmonth = "7" Then
            myDir = dstDir & "\" & Year(objFile.DateLastModified) & " - " & "July"
        ElseIf strmonth = "8" Then
            myDir = dstDir & "\" & Year(objFile.DateLastModified) & " - " & "August"
        ElseIf strmonth = "9" Then
            myDir = dstDir & "\" & Year(objFile.DateLastModified) & " - " & "September"
        ElseIf strmonth = "10" Then
            myDir = dstDir & "\" & Year(objFile.DateLastModified) & " - " & "October"
        ElseIf strmonth = "11" Then
            myDir = dstDir & "\" & Year(objFile.DateLastModified) & " - " & "November"
        ElseIf strmonth = "12" Then
            myDir = dstDir & "\" & Year(objFile.DateLastModified) & " - " & "December"
        End If
        If objFSO.FolderExists(myDir) Then
            'If directory exists, move the file there.
            objFSO.CopyFile objFile.Path, myDir & "\" & objFile.Name
            objFSO.DeleteFile objFile
        Else
            'Otherwise create the directory and then move the file there.
            objFSO.CreateFolder(myDir)
            objFSO.CopyFile objFile.Path, myDir & "\" & objFile.Name
            objFSO.DeleteFile objFile
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: If you know how-to process all `objFile` object in `objFolder.files` collection then you could apply it as `For Each objFoldr in objFolder.SubFolders`. See [FileSystemObject Collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x75sb7ff(v=vs.84).aspx) doc.

Comment: For increased performance, I'd definitely replace your `If...ElseIf...Else` statements with `Select Case strMonth`

Comment: @VictorMoraes In this particular case using the [`MonthName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58f13257.aspx) function is probably a better approach: `myDir = dstDir & "\" & Year(objFile.DateLastModified) & " - " & MonthName(Month(objFile.DateLastModified))`. Or perhaps a [`Dictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4.aspx) lookup if the OP wants month names in a different language than defined by the locale.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers you are absolutely right. I haven't thought about that